# How can convert a For statement into LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, for-loop, resharper

Ho can I convert a for statement into LINQ?

Supposed I have a method.

```
public void Method_One(){
     //...code...
     //...code...
}
```

And I have to call these code several times, the numbers of iteration will be my parameter as well.

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; ++i){
    Method_One();
}
```

I know there is conversion for foreach-statement but how about FOR?

Comment: Why tag it ReSharper? The tool should tell you how to convert it.

Comment: LINQ is not `for/foreach` replacement. And is for querying, not invoking actions.

Answer (score 4):

```
Enumerable.Range(0, numbers.Length).ToList().ForEach(arg => Method_One());
```

Agreed with @Ivan Stoev, its still a round about way of doing thing using a linq.

Instead of Linq a simple helper static method should make it more readable.

```
public static void Repeater(int count, Action action)
{
    Debug.Assert(action!=null);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        action();
}

//Use it like this
Repeater(10, Method_One);
```

Comment: what is `ForEach` here?

Comment: Hmm, `IEnumerable<T>` has no `ForEach` method.

Comment: You could add `ToList()` if you want to use ForEach, but still it's an overkill

Comment: @KamilT Absolutely. Especially comparing it to the converted single line original with curly braces removed: `for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; ++i)  Method_One();`

Comment: Repeater is perfect!

Comment: Since `Repeater` is *public*, please, *validate* `action` - what if `action == null?` (and may be `count` as well)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *force* Linq to do something, then *materialize*:

```
  Enumerable
    .Range(0, numbers.Length)
    .Select(item => {
       Method_One(); // you may want Method_One(item);

       return 0; // you have to return something
     })
    .ToList(); // materialization, to make Linq do
```

However, Linq *has not been designed* for such use and so the query looks *ugly*. A loop like

```
  foreach (var item in numbers)
    Method_One(); // you may want Method_One(item);
```

is far *better* code.

Answer (score 0):

When you can use `foreach` you can allways use `for` and thus also a simple LINQ (asuming `numbers` is a `List`): Otherwise convert it to a List before using `IEnumerable<T>.ToList()`.

```
numbers.ForEach(Method_One)
```

Which is equivalent to

```
numbers.ForEach(x => Method_One());
```

And also:

```
foreach(int i in numbers) Method_one();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
numbers.ForEach(num =>
{
  MethodOne();
});
```

And if you need to pass the curent number into function, it will be

```
MethodOne(num);
```